# Best way for beginner to learn JavaScript and PHP coding

Tags: php, javascript

I have a job interview coming up and in job description it states I need to be able to write JavaScript and PHP coding. Now its been a while since I did JavaScript and PHP coding. I am planning to use w3schools to be able to start of with the basics.

But my question is what is the best way on learning these web programming languages? Is it through books or through the web? If anyone know any sites which gan be helpful to learn or to be able to take tutorials in then please can you give me some links to check out?

Answer (score 1):

Although w3schools contain lot of basic information, most of it maybe outdated ones as they do not try to update the site as required, especially since all of newbies would look to learn stuff from w3. I wouldnt suggest you completely depend on w3. For php, you can use [php.net](http://php.net) site which would be ideal. See [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com) to understand what i am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

[Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/learn) is a very useful, fee website to learn coding on.